Updating input field in Blazor fails
    <input value="@Answer" @oninput="OnInput" />

Enter any series of digits.
If you enter more than two digits, input will be cleared.
If you enter '12', input will be cleared.
Same should happen for 8. I can't see why it fails.
@code {
    private string Answer = "";
    private string input = "";
    private string updated = "";

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e) {
        string answer = e.Value!.ToString()!;
        input = ":" + answer;
        if (answer == "12" || answer == "8") {   // correct answer!
            Answer = "";
    //        if (answer.Length == 1) {
    //            Console.WriteLine(Answer);
    //        }  // uncomment this if you want to add a breakpoint when it should clear
        } else if (answer.Length > 2) {
            Answer = "";
        } else {
            Answer = answer;
        }
        updated = ":" + Answer + ":";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Try it here:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/bgudkadp

Definitely seems strange behaviour.  You can however code it a little differently using binding to get it to work:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

Welcome to your new app.

<input class="form-control mb-2" @bind="Answer" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="OnAfter" />

<div>
    <pre>input: @input</pre>
    <pre>Answer: @Answer</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private string Answer = "";
    private string input = "";
    private string updated = "";

    private void OnAfter()
    {
        input = ":" + Answer;

        if (Answer == "12" || Answer == "8")
            Answer = "";

        else if (Answer.Length > 2)
            Answer = "";

        updated = ":" + Answer + ":";
    }
}


That did the trick. I had tried @bind="Answer" @bind:event="oninput" but I didn't know about @bind:after and didn't particularly want to use a property.

@BWhite, you can use the reverse quote (i.e. where the tilde mark is) to put code blocks in comments like this

Also note you can use @bind:set and @bind:get where you need to.  This is all Razor syntax.

I tested your code and found that is has nothing to do with condition  'Answer == "8"'. But it does not work with any single digit, the reason being the single digit input takes time in keyboard buffer, so if we delay updating textbox then we can make OP's code work, here're the changes which use JavaScript function to clear textbox.
@page "/"

@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

Welcome to your new app.

<input @ref=@txt value="@Answer" @oninput="OnInput" />

<div>
    <pre>input: @input</pre>
    <pre>Answer: @Answer</pre>
</div>


@code {
    private string Answer = "";
    private string input = "";
    private string updated = "";

    private ElementReference txt;

    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        string answer = e.Value!.ToString()!;
        input = ":" + answer;
        if (answer == "12" || answer == "8")
        {   // correct answer!
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("clearTextBox", txt);
            //        if (answer.Length == 1) {
            //            Console.WriteLine(Answer);
            //        }  // uncomment this if you want to add a breakpoint when it should clear
        }
        else if (answer.Length > 2)
        {
            Answer = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Answer = answer;
        }
        updated = ":" + Answer + ":";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

The JavaScript function
function clearTextBox(el) {    
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.value = "";
    }, 10);
}


NONONOO.  You do not do this in Blazor, ever.  No.  If you don't know what you're doing, then please just wait until Shaun or someone answers, don't confuse a new guy with this nonsense.

Isn't JS interop part of Blazor? please come up with reason and solution if you have and let the OP decide

There are things you COULD do in a personal project if you didn't have time to google the correct answer, and things you should ADVISE people to do who are trying to learn about Blazor.  The OP question is about a fundamental feature of Blazor, and has a specific correct answer, which Shaun (as usual) has given.  Yes, Javascript Interop is a feature of Blazor.  But that should be reserved for things like audio recording or video streaming, which Blazor doesn't currently handle-- not as a hack for people who haven't taken the time to learn the basics.

Question still remains why "if (answer == "12" || answer == "8") " is failing to work as intended without throwing any error/warning, do you see any thing wrong here if "answer == "12" works and answer == "8" doesn't . If three's any specific reason please explain to us. I agree there's nothing wrong with Shaun's answer..

If you think your logic is okay, but you get surprising results, I'd first check for race conditions.  These are VERY dangerous and insidious in Blazor, because on your dev system, an async issue doesn't always cause a failure-- but when you add latency with the web, you could get a failure most of the time.  In this case, we are changing the value of the input in the same method that is handling a change to value.  When you press "8", what happens first-- handling the @oninput, or inserting the "8" to the <input> object?

I think there may be an issue here somewhere in the Blazor code.  An input should not act differently to the first input. I was planning to raise an issue on the subject.
